# Why do I get such a messed up output?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, words

I'm writing a program to print the occurrences of letters and (one, two, three letter, etc..) words. So far I've gotten the letter part to work properly but I can't get the word part to work at all let alone differentiate between one, two, or three letter words. I tried to find out where the program was messing up, and it seems to be at the point I try to store them in the array "word".

Someone suggested strlok() but didn't mention how.

EDIT: I've substituted strlen() with sizeof() and have set my 'i' variable = 0 where it should be, but my output remains the first letter of the whole string and some strange character.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
void findLetters(char *ptr);
void findWords(char *point);


int main()
{
    char textStream[100]; //up to 98 characters and '\n\ and '\0'

    printf ( "enter some text\n");
    if ( fgets( textStream, sizeof ( textStream), stdin)) //input up to 99 characters
    {
        findLetters(textStream);
    }
    else
    {
        printf ( "fgets failed\n");
    }
    findWords(textStream);
    return 0;
}

void findLetters(char *ptr) //find occurences of all letters
{
    int upLetters[26];
    int loLetters[26];
    int i;
    int index;

    for ( i = 0; i < 26; i++) // set array to all zero
    {
        upLetters[i] = 0;
        loLetters[i] = 0;
    }
    i = 0;
    while ( ptr[i] != '\0') // loop until prt[i] is '\0'
    {
        if (ptr[i] >= 'A' && ptr[i] <= 'Z') //stores occurrences of uppercase letters
        {
            index = ptr[i] - 'A';// subtract 'A' to get index 0-25
            upLetters[index]++;//add one
        }

        if (ptr[i] >= 'a' && ptr[i] <= 'z') //stores occurrences of lowercase letters
        {
            index = ptr[i] - 'a';//subtract 'a' to get index 0-25
            loLetters[index]++;//add one
        }
        i++;//next character in ptr
    }
    printf("Number of Occurrences of Uppercase letters\n\n");
    for ( i = 0; i < 26; i++)//loop through 0 to 25
    {
        if ( upLetters[i] > 0)
        {
            printf("%c : \t%d\n", (char)(i + 'A'), upLetters[i]);
            // add 'A' to go from an index back to a character
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("Number of Occurrences of Lowercase letters\n\n");
    for ( i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        if ( loLetters[i] > 0)
        {
            printf("%c : \t%d\n", (char)(i + 'a'), loLetters[i]);
            // add 'a' to go back from an index to a character
        }
    }
}

void findWords(char *point)
{
    int i = 0; 
    int k = 0; 
    int count = 0;
    int j = 0; 
    int space = 0;
    int c = 0;
    char word[50][100], word1[50][100];

    for (;i < sizeof(point);i++) //counts # of spaces between words
    {
        if ((point[i] == ' ')||(point[i] == ',')||(point[i] == '.'))
        {
            space++;
        }
    }
    i = 0; 
    for(; i < sizeof(point); i++) //seperates strings from each other
    {
        if(point[i] == '.' || point[i] == 44|| point[i] == 46)
        {
            word[j][k] = '\0';
            j++;
            k = 0;
            printf("%s\n",point[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            word[j][k] = point[i];
            k++;
        }
        printf("%s\n",word[j]);
    }
    k = 0;

    for (i = 0;i <= space;i++) 
    {
        for (j = 0;j <= space;j++) 
        {
            if (i == j) // finds occurrences of words
            {
                strcpy(word1[k], word[i]); //copies words in new array
                k++;
                count++;

            } 
            else if(strcmp(word1[j], word[i]) != 0) //makes sure that the word copied equals the word from the string
            {
                ;
            }
        }
    }
    j = 0;
    i = 0;
    for (;i < count ;i++) 
    {
        for (;j <= space;j++)
        {
            if (strcmp(word1[i], word[j]) == 0) //counts occurrence of each word
            {
                c++;
            }
        }
        printf("%s \t %d times\n", word1[i], c);
        c = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you described what you mean by "messed up". What is your input, what do you get as output and what did you expect instead?

Comment: `char *word = strtok(point," ,.");` returns each word. Use this loop after the `strtok`: `while(word != NULL){ printf("Word:%s\n",word); word = strtok(NULL," ,."); }`

Comment: Clearly, if the `fgets()` fails, you shouldn't be doing `findWords()` any more than you do `findLetters()`.  However, that's unlikely to be your main problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll see if these help. And the messed up output is just the first letter in the string typed and some strange character.

Comment: Don't change the question to incorporate the answers, it makes the question and answers look nonsense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems in you code:

- `for(;i < strlen(point); i++) //seperates strings from each other` When this line is executed the value of `i` is already `strlen` and therefore the following `for` is not executed. Add `i=0` to fix it.
- You should use `sizeof` not strlen, otherwise you miss the last word.
- `if(point[i] == '.' || point[i] == 44|| point[i] == 46)` you are not checking for `' '` here. The correct if condition should be: 
  `if(point[i] == ' ' || point[i] == '.'|| point[i] == ' ')`
- Your code does not take into account the case where you have a comma and a space together.
- The algorithm you're using to find a word in the array is flawed. 
  You should use something like this :

```
how_many_times(word[i], word, number_of_words);

int how_many_times(char * word, char words[50][100], int how_many_words) {
  int i = 0, counter=0;                                                                         
  for (i=0; i< how_many_words; i++) {
    if ( strcmp(words[i], word) == 0 ) {
      counter++;
    }
  } 
  return counter;
}
```

Comment: If you want t indent code in lists, use 8 spaces. Otherwise, use 4

Answer (score 1):

A major problem is your second loop does not run:

```
    int i=0;
    for (;i < strlen(point);i++) //counts # of spaces between words
    {
      ...
    }

    for(;i < strlen(point); i++) //seperates strings from each other
    {
      ...
    }
```

`i` is still `strlen(point)-1` at the start of the second `for` loop so does not run. I would recommend always specifying the start point in a for loop, and also calculate string length only once, not each loop.

```
int len = strlen(point);
for (i=0; i < len; i++)
```

Comment: Unless you're modifying the length of the string in `point`, using `for (i = 0; i < strlen(point); i++)` is a bad idea because it converts the loop from being O(N) to O(N^2) where N is the length of the string, making the loop a quadratic algorithm.

Comment: Why would this make a difference?

Comment: @Sosa are you asking that about my answer or Jonathan's comment?

Comment: @weston Jonathan's comment is what I'm asking about; I understand your answer.

Comment: You should use @ and their name to get their attention, otherwise he won't know you replied to him. He is saying that because `strlen` is implemented with a loop, that as it stands you have nested loops that run in quadratic time. For a length 10 string, time would be 100, for a length 20 string, time would be 400, not double.